# Bar Plots with two variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar plot, with both `base r` plotting and `geom_point` plot with `ggplot` to visualize two variables by a column of factors.

I have created a datasheet that uses r-squared values for `Species` and `Elasmobranch` variables calculated using each factor.

```
 Graph <- structure(list(Factors = structure(c(5L, 4L, 11L, 6L, 8L, 10L
  ), .Label = c("Activity", "Bait", "Depth", "Location", "Marine Park", 
  "Month", "Sea State", "Start Time", "Substrate", "Swell", "Year"
  ), class = "factor"), Species = c(0.1064, 0.5806, 0.05974, 0.07888, 
  0.1325, 0.05725), Elasmobranchs = c(0.02658, 0.4074, 0.02072, 
  0.1419, 0.1065, 0.08661)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

  ggplot(data = Graph, aes(x = Species, y = Factors, colour = Factors)) +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    xlab("Species Richness") +
    ylab("Factors") +
    theme_classic()

  barplot(Species~Factors, xlab="Factors", ylab="R-Sqaured Values", 
  horizontal = TRUE,
    main = "Factor correlations with species richness", frame.plot=FALSE)

  barplot(Elasmobranchs~Factors,  xlab="Factors", ylab="R-Sqaured Values", 
  horizontal = TRUE,
    main = "Factor correlations with species richness", frame.plot=FALSE)
```

These `ggplot` and standard plots work nicely, however I would simply like to add `Elasmobranchs` on the x-axis alongside `Species` and have the result displayed in decreasing order. Is there a simple way to do this by adding a small line of code to my existing plots?

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you're trying to do, you can reshape your data frame using `pivot_longer` (former `gather`) and then differentiate between `Species` and `Elasmobranchs` through `shape`. You can reverse the scale using `scale_x_reverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(data = Graph %>% pivot_longer(-Factors),
       aes(x = value, y = Factors, colour = Factors, shape=name)) +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    xlab("Species Richness") +
    ylab("Factors") +
    scale_x_reverse() +
    theme_classic()
```

EDIT:

In case you're working with an older version of `tidyr` that doesn't have `pivot_longer` function, you can use `gather` (from the same package).

```
ggplot(data = Graph %>% gather("name", "value", -Factors),
       aes(x = value, y = Factors, colour = Factors, shape=name)) +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    xlab("Species Richness") +
    ylab("Factors") +
    scale_x_reverse() +
    theme_classic()
```

[image: example]

EDIT 2:

To reorder the `y-axis` based on the values of `x-axis`.

```
ggplot(data = Graph %>% gather("name", "value", -Factors), 
       aes(x = value, y = fct_reorder(Factors, value), colour = Factors, shape=name)) +
    geom_point(size = 3) +
    xlab("Species Richness") +
    ylab("Factors") +
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I have just tried to re-create this graph and R has thrown an error: Error in Graph %>% pivot_longer(-Factors) : could not find function "%>%"

Comment: Oh sorry about that - you have to load `tidyr` or `tidyverse` first. `pivot_longer` comes from `tidyr`. If you don't have the latest version, then try `gather` instead (but then change `name` to `key` - this function has different default values).

Comment: And maybe you can even remove the coloring based on `Factors`, because it adds no value to the graph (it's already on the y-axis). So maybe use `name` to color instead and remove the `shape`. That way you can quickly differentiate between `Elasmobranchs` and `Species` based on color.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have loaded tidyverse and then got the error: Error in pivot_longer(., -Factors) : 
  could not find function "pivot_longer" when trying to install gather :install.packages("gather")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Brian/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘gather’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0)

Comment: Yeah, you have an older version of `tidyr`. `gather` is not a package, but another function from `tidyr`. I've updated my answer above to show you how to use that function.

Comment: Wonderful, that works very well!!! Now I wonder if there is a way to display the points in a decreasing order (from highest to lowest values - top-bottom).

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to order exactly. Do you want to keep the x-axis in the usual 0-0.6 order and then sort the y-axis, so that it shows categories in an order based on `Species Richness`? In that case, `Location` would be on top as it has the highest values and `Year` on the bottom. Check the new edit.

Comment: `fct_reorder` is from `forcats` that's a part of `tidyverse`.

Comment: Excellent!! All works well, had to download the package "forcats" for the fct_reorder function to work!!